# php facebook autopost in my fan page visible to all member?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have seen plenty of posts for posting with php in facebook and have already used some and manage to autopost on my facebook fan page..... BUT..... only the users that have my app can see those posts on my fan page

isnt a way to post on my fan page and all the members can see it?... am admin of my page... i accept the app permissions for stream publish and manage pages, even for offline access even its not needed.

has anyone any ideas how i can autopost and all can see them? i prefer php but i dont mind even if its with js

Comment: what kind of app is it? you post to wall? or to your app? what's your page url?

Answer (score 1):

You need 'manage_pages' permission to post on page wall also check if your page is published or not

```
 $attachment =  array(
            'access_token' => $pageAccessToken,
            'name' => $title,
            'link' => $url,
            'description' => $desc
            );
            }

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$pid.'/feed');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can post on my facebook page or even my own wall(depending of the pid i use), my problem is that people who dont use the app cant see the posts